# Apache Spark - more partitions, slower performance

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have been running an Apache Spark program on EC2 and my results are showing that by partitioning the data into the recommended 2-3 partitions per core is far slower than using the (seemingly) default partitions of 2.

Nanoseconds to complete without partitioning:

```
u1 - 650472112996
u2 - 654525970891
u3 - 498530412012
u4 - 568162162934
u5 - 659015135256
```

The number of total partitions was 2, I checked using `sparkContext.partitions.size`. *

Nanoseconds to complete with 2 partitions per core (total of 32 partitions):

```
u1 - 1562831187137
u2 - 1690008041723
u3 - 1652170780785
u4 - 3381857826333 
u5 - 3969656930184
```

This particular sets of experiments was run across a 16 node cluster.

While without partitioning takes approximately 10 minutes every time, with partitioning took anywhere from 25-60 minutes! The exact same program and parameters were used. Checking the Spark UI showed that the datafile was too big for the default partitioned nodes and often data was spilled to disk, this never occurred when using 32 partitions. Additionally, only ever 2 tasks could be run on the default partitioned run (as clearly, there's only 2 partitions); meanwhile, the 32 partition cluster has 16 tasks running concurrently. I would've thought the partitioned run would've been quicker, not slower!

What could cause such a decrease in speed? Shuffling of data across the nodes perhaps? Also, why would one run, i.e. `u1`, take 25 minutes and another run, i.e. `u5`, take 1 hour on the 32 partitioned cluster, but when ran with default partitioning they took about the same time?

- Apache Spark docs say that the number of partitions will be equal to the number of cores in the cluster; however, I have tested this across cluster sizes ranging from 2 - 20, using different EC2 instances, and every time it defaults to 2 partitions.

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: Via S3. It's then cached.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I will get it up asap. I think it has too many joins.